# How to undo NetworkManager changes

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, networkmanager

I accidentally modified NetworkManager with the command.

```
nmcli con modify eno1 ipv4.dns-options 'single-request-reopen timeout:2 ndots:0'
```

I think the modification hasn't been activated since I haven't restarted the device.

I don't know the previous value of the setting.

How can I undo the modification to the previous one?

Answer (score 2):

Set it to the empty string, which also happens to be the default.

```
# nmcli c m eno1 ipv4.dns-options ''
```

You will then see that the field has reverted to its default value.

```
# nmcli --fields ipv4.dns-options c s eno1
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
```

Comment: I found that this turned to empty(default) but not to the previous value.

Comment: @kujiy It's not normally necessary to set these options at all, so the empty string is fine. Unless you absolutely know you need one of the options to solve a specific problem (and on a normal network that's unlikely).